# How to remove the appended String in java

Tags: java

So I have a file path which includes the filename along with extension and have appended System.currentmillis().Now If a condition is met I would like to remove the System.CurrentMillis from it .How can I do that?.The file path looks something like this

```
String filePath = someClass.getFile()+System.currentTimeMillis()+".txt";
```

Any help would be appreciated.Thanks in advance

Comment: Can the filename contain the year 2001's timestamp or before. Or can we assume it will be the latest timestamp?

Comment: It would be latest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't answer this in general without knowing what the file name is, in particular with which character that file name might end.  If we assume that the file name would *not* end in a digit, we can try:

```
String filePath = "some_file1576645285164.txt";
System.out.println(filePath);
String output = filePath.replaceAll("\\d+(\\.[^.]+)$", "$1");
System.out.println(output);
```

This prints:

```
some_file1576645285164.txt
some_file.txt
```

Comment: Can we do it using Array as well?

Comment: @Aria I don't understand your comment, can you elaborate?

Comment: What I meant is if we can use Array and then split it

Comment: Actually, it happens the other way around, i.e. you split the string on some regex, which generates an array.  No, that approach would be more complicated than my current answer, in my estimate.

Comment: I m asking Beacuse there is possibility that my file name will end up with digits at the end.If you could help

Comment: There isn't really a fool-proof way to handle this scenario.  You should write the files initially with a delimiter, e.g. `-`, between the file name and UNIX timestamp.  Otherwise, it might not be possible to tease apart the components.

Answer (score 0):

The length of **System.currentTimeMillis()** now is **13** and it will take more than **200** years for its size to increase by 1. Hence I am trying to find the index of extension and using it to remove the timestamp from the file path.

```
    String fileName = "fileName1576647662124.txt";
    String extension = ".txt";
    int extensionIndex = fileName.indexOf(extension);
    System.out.println(fileName.substring(0, extensionIndex - 13) + extension);
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that files with an earlier year could fail with your logic.  E.g. the year 1998 is `900000000000`, only 12 digits.

Comment: But in the problem statement, it is mentioned that they are using System.currentTimeMillis() which is of length 13 till 200 years. That is the assumption I have before proposing the solution.

Comment: You're missing the point of my comment.  What if they have a file from say 1998 or even 2001, which ended in a digit?  In this case, the epoch timestamp would only be _12_, not 13, digits, and your answer would not work.

Comment: The answer that I wrote is w.r.t problem mentioned. It is not foolproof. @Aria said the file name contains the latest timestamps only.